# JavaScript Object/Array access question

Tags: javascript

Set an object, with some data.

```
var blah = {};
blah._a = {};
blah._a._something = '123';
```

Then wish to try and access, how would I go about doing this correctly?

```
var anItem = 'a';
console.log(blah._[anItem]);
console.log(blah._[anItem]._something);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation) should look like this:

```
var anItem = 'a';
console.log(_glw['_'+anItem]);
console.log(_glw['_'+anItem]._something);
```

[You can test it here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/Uu2Gt/) (note that I replaced `_glw` with `blah` in the demo to match the original object).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand the question, but here are some basics.

```
var foo = {};

// These two statements do the same thing
foo.bar = 'a';
foo['bar'] = 'a';

// So if you need to dynamically access a property
var property = 'bar';
console.log(foo[property]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = {};
obj.anotherObj = {};
obj.anotherObj._property = 1;
var item = '_property';
// the following lines produces the same output
console.log(obj.anotherObj[item]);
console.log(obj.anotherObj['_property']);
console.log(obj.anotherObj._property);
```